# Where is the fotorama media gallery put together?

Tags: magento2, media-images, fotorama

**Magento 2.4.6**

Id like to add a little extra code to the media gallery which shows the images below the main image. Id like to do that for a configurable product. I checked `gallery.js` and `fotorama.js` but wasnt able to find the place where the actual images are being inserted.

Any ideas?

Thanks!